# Finding sum of greatest integer function of every element of an array(Optimisation)

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, floor

Given an array say `a`, and a number say `x`, the task is to write a program to get the sum of every element's greatest integer function when `x` is divided to every element of `a`.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

result = gif(1/x) + gif(2/x) + gif(3/x) + gif(4/x), gif(5/x)
```

This can be easily done with the help of a loop, but I want to know whether is there a way the above task can be done more quickly and efficiently(without using loops).

Comment: It's more a question for another SE site, like maths...

Comment: Why do you think that that is possible ?

Comment: Well, I thought there might be a formula or shortcut on computing `GIF` for large sized arrays(upto 10**5), rather than traversing every element.

Comment: What is known about the array elements? In your example, you have `a[i] = i+1`. This is probably not always true.

Comment: @Henrik consider it as a random example, array can contain any set of elements.

Comment: Do you do integer division ? or floating division ?

Comment: integer division.

Comment: Why do you need to compute that huge sum ? I can be helpful to know. [An efficient way to optimize some processing is to avoid performing it :-) ]

Comment: How is your data distributed ?

Answer (score 1):

No processing of an array can be done without using a loop when the outcome depends on the individual values and you know nothing about them. That's a universal and inescapable rule.

Comment: I dunno. This is needlessly pessimistic. A huge part of optimization is figuring out algorithms that don't need to loop over every datum. I don't know whether that's possible in this case, but a blanket statement against it seems unfounded. Maybe you have a specific argument for this case.

Comment: @RobertDodier: this is the most elementary statement from the theory of algorithm complexity: the complexity cannot be lower than the input size. But it is also common sense: you must get the values !

Comment: OK. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid loops, I suppose it could be written as a recursive function, but I wouldn't expect that to be pretty or to be faster.

If you know x ahead of time, there may be options for doing some of the work as elements are added to the array.

Otherwise the best option for speed may (depending on the size of the array) be to split the array and use multiple loops in parallel and then add up the results.

If you are using C++ then using one of the stl standard algorithms may be faster than your explicitly written loop.

Comment: "using one of the stl standard algorithms may be faster than your explicitly written loop": by what magic ??

Comment: It may be, but it may not be, it depends on how well written the loop version is, but Scott Meyers made the case for them in Effective STL. Efficiency isn't the only reason he gives, but it is one of them. C++17 introduces parallel versions of some algorithms too.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What can beat a simple loop ?

Comment: When you say that doesn't answer your question, you mean that you read the book I mentioned and it didn't answer your question?

Comment: Letting someone purchase a book and read it thoroughly cannot be called answering a question. How can an STL construction beat a custom loop ?

Comment: As part of my answer of the original question I said it might beat the a loop written by the OP. I dont go into why it might beat it (which is your question) but I do reference a well respected source that goes into much more depth on it than I could. As part of his answer he does allow that maybe the stl implementation uses a loop, but it can also use implementation detail that is not available to the caller (it might be implementation specific), in that case it stands a chance of being a better implemented loop. I said may be better - not will always be better, it should be at least as good.

Comment: Another thing that can beat a simple loop :  more than one loop running at the same time.

Comment: Yep, automatic parallelization will yield better results and won't be performed by the compiler on the custom loop (any way it will perform automatic vectorization). This said, how can you miss a `for (i= 0; i<n; i++)` loop ? (If you manage, you can also miss the use of an stl gadget.)

Comment: you mean as in using i as an index to repeated use random access where sequential access could be faster? and you'll be relying on the compiler to actually treat i++ as ++i   A good modern compiler will help out, but if it didn't then even that tiny piece of code could have been improved on.